# Magento 2 - Setup blog on subdomain

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, websites, blog, subdomain

There is an option on magento to setup multiple website. But I don't want to do that. I need a subdomain for my blog like this:

> blog.example.com

I don't want customers to lose their sessions and cart items whenever they go to blog subdomain.

Is there any way to achieve this?